# How can I make the up and down arrow keys navigate a table's rows, and programmatically apply the sudo :hover to those rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I have an input of type text that is used to perform asynchronous table row searches using jquery.
I have an .on function attached to the search input and on key down, I'm calling a function called hoverDown(). What I would like to happen when the down arrow key is pressed, is to hover over the table rows. And when a table row is hovered over with the arrow key, and the user hits enter, I would like for the href to fire and take the user to that related page. I am able to detect the e.keyCode but that's about as far as I've been able to get and I really don't know where to take it from here. Relevant Code:

//HTML

```
<div id="main">
<input type="text" class="table-search" id="search" autocomplete="off"   placeholder="Search Clients…">
<table class="table" id="tblData">
<thead><tr><th>Name</th> <th>Title</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">Scott</a></td> <td>Client</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">Billy</a></td><td>Client</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">George</a></td><td>Client</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">Sara</a></td><td>Client</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">John</a></td><td>Client</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">Megan</a></td><td>Client</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">Ben</a></td><td>Client</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">Jully</a></td><td>Client</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">Bethany</a></td><td>Client</td></tr><tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">Alen</a></td><td>Client</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">Jane</a></td><td>Client</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://lar.loc/cases">Alice</a></td><td>Client</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

//javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main").on("keydown", "#search", function(e){
    hoverDown();
    });
});


function hoverDown()
{
    if ($(document).keydown()) {
        $(document).keydown(function(e){

            if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
                alert("down");
                e.keyCode = null;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
                alert("up");
                e.keyCode = null;
            }

        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I threw together a fiddle for you to play around with http://jsfiddle.net/7BcZA/2/

Summary:

When you "hover" a row, add a class to it. Mine is called `selected`. This identifies that it's selected, as well as adds CSS styling. Remove the class `selected` from the previous `tr` that was selected.

Get the next or previous tag based on which was button was pressed.

As a bonus, I added the "press enter" functionality that you were looking for `=)`.

Comment: marking should be done with classes, not attributes, then you can use CSS styling to get your highlighting "for free".

Comment: That's still messy as hell - see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/JjX6c/ for my version.

Comment: @Alnitak Nice work. I didn't mention it earlier but I'm using [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) to load my page content dynamically. For whatever reason when the links are programmatically clicked using window.location, the pjax no longer works, but instead an entire page load and refresh is performed. There has got to be a way keep the pjax loading the content dynamically.

Comment: @Scotty that sounds like a separate question to me

Comment: @Phil Bozak - your jsfiddle no longer exists at that URL.

Comment: fiddle is no more exists