# How can we make HTML table with arrow keys navigation in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating simple HTML table and want to navigate all cells using arrow keys in React. Simply I want to add accessibility feature using keyword in table. I saw many article but unable to achieve this navigation feature.

Comment: What have you tried? There's articles and SO posts about basic table navigation with arrow keys. And about key press logic handling in React. What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: I was seeing this link which was in jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817451/use-arrow-keys-to-navigate-an-html-table . I was trying to create navigation in react but unable to create.